# How to test that bottom sheet that use useRef open?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library

In react native, I have a bottom sheet that I'd like to test it opens properly when clicking on a button.
The bottomsheet is from the library [Gorhom bottom sheet](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet) and it uses useRef with a method (extend, present...).
I've tried to test my component without mocking the method on the useRef but I get an error  `_addChannelBsRef$curr.present is not a function` .

But if I mock the the useRef with the method, the bottom sheet won't open.

How can I test that ?

Here sample of my code :

Component that triggers the function :

```
    const VerticalKlubListItemNewChannel = ({
  openAddChannelBs,
  selectedKlub,
}: VerticalKlubListItemNewChannelProps) => {


  const pressAddNewChannel = () => {
    openAddChannelBs();
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      testID={BtnTestIds.openNewChannelBtn}
      onPress={pressAddNewChannel}
      style={styles.container}>
      <CustomText color={colorsTheme.primary} fontWeight="semiBold">
        new channel
      </CustomText>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ) : null;
};
```

The function that is passing down to the component :

```
 const openAddChannelBs = useCallback(() => {
    addChannelBsRef.current?.present();

  }, []);
```

And my test looks like this :

```
describe("AddNewChannelBottomSheet", () => {
  it("open the bottom sheet onPress button", async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <LeftDrawerChannel navigation={navigation as any} />,
      {
        preloadedState: {
          channel: {
            currentSelectedKlub: { user: { klubRole: "admin" } },
          } as any,
        },
      },
    );

    const { getByText } = render(
      <AddNewchannelBs
        addChannelBsRef={
          mockOpenBsRef as unknown as BottomSheetModaleContainerRefType
        }
      />,
    );

    const openBsAddNewchannel = getByTestId(BtnTestIds.openNewChannelBtn);

    expect(openBsAddNewchannel).toBeTruthy();

    fireEvent.press(openBsAddNewchannel);

    const getText = getByText(
      "Enter the name of the channel that will be visible to members",
    );

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(getText).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of present() try expand() method like below, it should work

```
const openAddChannelBs = useCallback(() => {
  addChannelBsRef.current?.expand();
}, []);
```